# recurrence relation related problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, relations

I'm having some difficulties of finding the recurrence relations of;

1. *number of divisions of internal region of n sided polygon*
2. *number of paths from one point to another point in an NxN grid*

Can anyone guide me in approaching in a way to a solution?

**EDIT**: I guess the solution of both problems is the [catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)

[image: pic1]

Well I need recurrence relation for them and mostly a basic idea of finding it

Comment: what are the divisions of a polygon ? smaller triangles that all share the center of the polygon as a vertex ?

Comment: in the grid, what moves can you do ? just bottom and right, to go from top left corner to bottom right ?

Comment: Yes. The answers are as you say.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a polygon with n vertices, you know that 2 consecutive vertices make a triangle with the center of the polygon. No need for recursion. There are n such regions.
2. This looks pretty complicated. If you say your grid is NxM then at the first step either you go down (new grid : N-1xM) or you go right (new grid : NxM-1) so $C(N, M) = C(N-1, M) + C(N, M-1)$ + limit conditions when N or M is equal to 1.
   If you have a closed formula it should be easy to check it with this formula else I didn't look more into it yet